# Security rule has invalid Port range terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Unable to provide destination_port_range for nsg security rule in azure using terraform.
Terraform v0.12.28 provider.azurerm v2.18.0

```
security_rule {
    name                       = "databricks-control-plane-inbound-rule"
    priority                   = 110
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = 225557
  }
```

> Error: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error:
> Code="SecurityRuleInvalidPortRange" Message="Security rule has invalid
> Port    range. Value provided: 225557. Value should be an integer OR
> integer range    with '-' delimiter. Valid range 0-65535." Details=[]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your issue, you want to add multiple destination ports in one NSG rule. So you need to use the `destination_port_ranges` instead of the `destination_port_range` like this:

```
security_rule {
    name                       = "databricks-control-plane-inbound-rule"
    priority                   = 110
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_ranges    = ["22", "5557"]
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `destination_port_range` in your security_rule is `225557`, which is not a valid port number because it has one digit too many. It should be a number between `0` and `65535`

Comment: Okay, for specifying a port range there is '-' as delimiter, so please try setting "22-5557".