# AKS cluster creation fails with error 'Security rule has invalid Port range'

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-aks

We are creating an AKS cluster, but it fails at the deployment stage with the below error,

```
'Security rule has invalid Port range. Value provided: 22,3389. Value should be an integer OR integer range with '-' delimiter. Valid range 0-65535.. Details: [] (Code: SecurityRuleInvalidPortRange)'
```

We tried using both UI and CLI, but it fails.
Please let me know if somebody is aware of this issue.

Thanks,
Arun

Comment: I think, the error message is saying clearly. Ideally port number should be selected from a range 0 to 65535. But it appear as you have mentioned port number - 223389.

Answer (score 0):

Problem you have mentioned is clear and says that you have defined wrong port number - `223389`. While port range is `0-65535`.

Probably you wanted to set up destination_port ranges- it should look like:  `destination_port_ranges    = ["22", "3389"]`

Similar problem: [invalid-port-range-aks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63016875/security-rule-has-invalid-port-range-terraform).

Comment: Yes, but I don't specify these ports anywhere during cluster deployment. still fails.

Comment: Can you please specify steps you have followed so far and tutorial you have used ?

Comment: Sure. I am Creating AKS cluster in azure portal . Neither portal ask you nor in CLI command we have to  give these port details. So i am not sure where exactly these ports details to enter in.

Comment: Can you also  provided AKS version, configuration parameters used (Node Network, Pod Network, Service Network) ?